# c# calling methods on panel?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, panel

I have created some new method:

```
void newMethod(int x, int y)
{
    Button B = new Button();
    B.Size = new Size(100, 30);
    B.Location = new Point(x, y);
    B.Text = "Text";
    Controls.Add(B);
}
```

Now I created a new panel inside some other method:

```
void Something()
{
    Panel P = new Panel();
    P.Size = new Size(300, 300);
    P.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    P.BackColor = new Color(Blue);
    Controls.Add(P);
}
```

How do I add my first method in which I've created a button, to a panel in my second method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parent control as parameter:

```
private void AddButton(int x, int y, Control parent)
{
    Button button = new Button
        {
            Size = new Size(100, 30),
            Location = new Point(x, y),
            Text = "Text"
        };

    parent.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Then:

```
void Something()
{
    Panel P = new Panel();
    P.Size = new Size(300, 300);
    P.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    P.BackColor = new Color(Blue);

    this.AddButton(100, 100, P);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this declaration gloabally. That is inside class not in NewMethod.

```
Panel P = new Panel();
```

Then write this code

```
this.P.controls.Add(B);
```

**insted of**

```
Controls.Add(B);
```

Comment: Notice that property `Controls` and method `Add` begin with capital letters

Comment: Thank you for try, but momently that is not the best suited for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your 1st method

```
void newMethod(int x, int y, Panel p)
{
    Button B = new Button();
    B.Size = new Size(100, 30);
    B.Location = new Point(x, y);
    B.Text = "Text";
    p.Controls.Add(B);
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea since I am not only using it for that panel, but rather for form itself and on other panels.